# grunt-shell task for running php from cli not found

Tags: javascript, php, shell, gruntjs, gruntfile

I'm starting with **grunt**.
I would like to execute several php files from CLI.

So i've installed grunt-shell with
`npm install --save-dev grunt-shell`

Now i have this gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({
    shell: {
      php: {
        multiple: {
          command:  [
            'php -f /home/leandro/oskar.php',
            'php -f /home/leandro/oskar2.php'
          ].join('&')
        }
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('default', ['shell:php']);
};
```

I've tried all the combinations of calling the task but the output is always:

`Warning: Task "shell:php" not found. Use --force to continue.
Aborted due to warnings.`

Answer (score 0):

well, i'm begining with Grunt and seems a package.json for node is mandatory.
it works with it! :)